# Converting String to Double in Excel / Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I try create new function in Excel, witch will counting given values (something like SUM function, but only with given prefix).

```
  A
---------    
1|AA30  
2|AA10 
3|BC446 
4|AA10

// result will be 50  on SUM_PREFIX(A1:A4;"AA")
```

Problem is, when the value is in the form e.g AA10,434  or AA4.43. Could me anyone help me with my problem? This is my first stript in VB.

```
 Function SUM_PREFIX(Data As Range, prefix As String) As Double

    Dim result As Double
    Dim strVal As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim objRegExp As Object

   Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
   With objRegExp
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "^[" + prefix + "]+[0-9]+(\,|\.)?[0-9]?$"
        .Global = True
    End With

    For i = 1 To Data.Rows.Count
        Debug.Print Data.Cells(i, 1)
        If objRegExp.Test(Data.Cells(i, 1)) = True Then
            strVal = Replace(Data.Cells(i, 1), prefix, "")
            Debug.Print strVal
            strVal = Trim(Replace(strVal, ",", "."))
            Debug.Print strVal
            result = result + CDbl(strVal)
        End If
    Next i

    SUM_PREFIX = result
End Function
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`CDbl` is locale-aware, so check if your `Replace` is correct (for example, in my locale, I have to replace "." by "," in order for it to work).
If you don't want to rely on locale-aware code, use `Val` instead of `CDbl` because `Val` only recognizes "." as a valid decimal separator regardless of locale.

Answer (score -1):

```
Function SUM_PREFIXO(DADOS As Range, PREFIXO As String) As Double

Dim result, NI As Double
Dim strVal As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim objRegExp As Object



   Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
   With objRegExp
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "^[" + PREFIXO + "]+[0-9]+(\,|\.)?[0-9]?$"
        .Global = True
    End With

    NI = DADOS.Rows.Count

    For i = 1 To DADOS.Rows.Count

    Debug.Print (DADOS.Cells(i, 1))

    If objRegExp.Test(RetiraEspaço(DADOS.Cells(i, 1))) = True Then
        strVal = Trim(Replace(DADOS.Cells(i, 1), PREFIXO, ""))
        Debug.Print strVal
        strVal = Trim(Replace(strVal, ".", ","))
        Debug.Print strVal
        strVal = Trim(Replace(strVal, ",", ","))
        Debug.Print strVal
        result = result + CDbl(strVal)

    End If
    Next i

SUM_PREFIXO = result
End Function
```

'Com o código abaixo pode-se
'remover os espaços extras entre as palavras de um texto:
Function RetiraEspaço(Texto)

```
Dim Vpalavra, inicio, termino, Wresultado
inicio = 1
Texto = UCase(Texto) & " "

Do Until InStr(inicio, Texto, " ") = 0
    termino = InStr(inicio, Texto, " ")
    Vpalavra = Mid(Texto, inicio, termino - inicio)
    inicio = termino + 1

    Wresultado = Wresultado & "" & Vpalavra
Loop

RetiraEspaço = Trim(Wresultado)
```

End Function