# Why does casting to double using "String * 1" fail? Will CDbl(String) work on all systems?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an application which contains the line below to assign a parsed XML value to a variant array.

```
V(2) = latNode.Text * 1
```

This works fine on my system (Windows 7, Excel 2010) but doesn't work on some other system or systems - and I've not been able to get a response from the user who reported the problem.

I've switched out the offending line for:

```
V(2) = CDbl(latNode.Text)
```

This still works on my system, but then I had no problem in the first place. The question is on what systems does the first approach fail and why, and will the second method always work? I'm sure I've used the "String * 1" trick elsewhere before and would like to know how concerned I should be about tracking down other occurrences.

Thanks.

Comment: Tested `String * 1` on an XP + Excel 2003 and it works. Are you sure `latNode.Text` is always a number string? Because if it's not, `CDbl` may still fail.

Comment: I prefer explicit conversions and would avoid the unnecessary multiplication so would use `CDbl(latNode.Text)` if I wanted `V(2)` to be floating point or `CLng(latNode.Text)` if I wanted it to be integer. However, `Variant = "Number" * 1` works for every Number I have tried with Vista and Excel 2003. I agree with Passerby, has your user encountered a rare situation in which `latNode.Text` is null or non-numeric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it's related to thousands separator and decimal mark. Office VBA uses cultural settings even in CDbl, in my German Excel version, it's reversed compared to English, `CDbl("123.4")` is parsed to 1234, `CDbl("123,4")` to 123.4.

`Val(x)` will always parse the dot as decimal mark.

Comment: The user got back to me to say their system uses comma as as decimal separator. The answer is to use 'Val(String)' as recommended in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063887/converting-string-to-double-and-computin-in-excel-macro

Comment: Ah yes, Val works right for the dot. It won't work for "," but thousands separators are quite unlikely to be found in any stored data.

Comment: It's latitude and longitude data in my case so certainly won't have any thousand separators.

Comment: If you want to edit your answer to add the Val() solution I'll accept it.